# Java. Проблема в обращении к окну

Tags: java, jframe

Доброго времени суток. Имеется код,в котором не работает функция `FSFullScreenActionPerformed`. Не работает она,как я понял,из-за того,что не знает к кому задать параметр `setContentPane()`. Что нужно исправить в коде,чтобы все заработало?

```
public class DIVISION extends JFrame {

int hor,vert,ma,mb;
String[] Language = {
        "English",
        "Русский",
    };
String tNewGame="Новая Игра";
String tSettings="Настройки";
String tExit="Выход";
String tFullScreen="Полноэкранный режим";
/*
tNewGame="New Game";
tSettings="Settings";
tExit="Exit";
tFullScreen="Full Screen";
*/

private JPanel MainMenu;
    private JButton MMNGame; 
    private JButton MMSettings; 
    private JButton MMExit; 

private JPanel FullSettingsMenu;
    private JButton FSMBack;
    private JCheckBox FSFullScreen; 
    private JComboBox FSSetLanguage;

private JPanel Menu;
    private JButton MExit;
    private JButton MBack;
    private JButton MSettings;

private JPanel SettingsMenu;
private JButton SMBack;
public DIVISION() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    vert = sSize.height;
    hor = sSize.width;
    //Setings of window//
    setSize(hor,vert);
    setResizable(false);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //----------------//

    //Setings of buttons//
    ma=(hor/4);//height//
    mb=(vert/10);//width//
    //------------------//


    MainMenu = new JPanel();
    MainMenu.setLayout(null);MainMenu.setBackground(Color.blue);
        MMNGame = new JButton(tNewGame);
            MMNGame.setSize(ma, mb);
            MMNGame.setLocation((hor/2)-(ma/2),300);
            MMNGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    MMNGameActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
        MMSettings = new JButton(tSettings);
            MMSettings.setSize(ma, mb);
            MMSettings.setLocation((hor/2)-(ma/2),400);
            MMSettings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    MMSettingsActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
        MMExit = new JButton(tExit);
            MMExit.setSize(ma, mb);
            MMExit.setLocation((hor/2)-(ma/2),500);
            MMExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    MMExitActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
    MainMenu.add(MMNGame);MainMenu.add(MMSettings);MainMenu.add(MMExit);

    FullSettingsMenu = new JPanel();
    FullSettingsMenu.setLayout(null);FullSettingsMenu.setBackground(Color.orange);
        FSMBack = new JButton("\u21B6");
            FSMBack.setSize(50, 50);
            FSMBack.setLocation(0,0);
            FSMBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    FSMBackActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
        FSFullScreen = new JCheckBox(tFullScreen);
            FSFullScreen.setSize(ma, mb);
            FSFullScreen.setLocation((hor/2)-(ma/2),400);
            FSFullScreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    FSFullScreenActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
        FSSetLanguage = new JComboBox(Language);
            FSSetLanguage.setSize(ma, mb);
            FSSetLanguage.setLocation((hor/2)-(ma/2),500);
    FullSettingsMenu.add(FSMBack);FullSettingsMenu.add(FSFullScreen);FullSettingsMenu.add(FSSetLanguage);

    SettingsMenu = new JPanel();
    SettingsMenu.setLayout(null);SettingsMenu.setBackground(Color.green);
        SMBack = new JButton("\u21B6");
            SMBack.setSize(ma, mb);
            SMBack.setLocation((hor/2)-(ma/2),300);
            SMBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    SMBackActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
    SettingsMenu.add(SMBack);

    Menu = new JPanel();
    Menu.setLayout(null);Menu.setBackground(Color.red);
        MBack = new JButton("\u21B6");
            MBack.setSize(50, 50);
            MBack.setLocation(0,0);
            MBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    MBackActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
        MSettings = new JButton(tSettings);
            MSettings.setSize(ma, mb);
            MSettings.setLocation((hor/2)-(ma/2),400);
            MSettings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    MSettingsActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
        MExit = new JButton(tExit);
            MExit.setSize(ma, mb);
            MExit.setLocation((hor/2)-(ma/2),500);
            MExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    MExitActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
    Menu.add(MBack); Menu.add(MSettings); Menu.add(MExit);

    add(MainMenu); 

}                      

private void MMNGameActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    //
}

private void MMSettingsActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   this.setContentPane(FullSettingsMenu);
   revalidate();
   repaint();
}

private void MMExitActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Exit();
}

private void FSMBackActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   this.setContentPane(MainMenu);
   revalidate();
   repaint();
}

private void FSFullScreenActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if(FSFullScreen.isSelected()==true){
        setContentPane(FullSettingsMenu);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        setUndecorated(true);
    }
    else{
        setContentPane(FullSettingsMenu);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        setUndecorated(false);
    }
}

private void MBackActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    //
}

private void MSettingsActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   this.setContentPane(SettingsMenu);
   revalidate();
   repaint();
}

private void MExitActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Exit();
}

private void SMBackActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   this.setContentPane(Menu);
   revalidate();
   repaint();
}

public void ButtonFocus(){

}

public void Exit(){
    System.exit(0);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new DIVISION().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникает при вызове метода `setUndecorated: The frame is displayable`

Вы не можете вызвать `setUndecorated(false)` после `pack()` и если `isVisible()==true`

вот исправленный вариант.

**UPD**

```
 private void FSFullScreenActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    dispose();
    setVisible(false);
    if(FSFullScreen.isSelected()==true){

        setContentPane(FullSettingsMenu);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        setUndecorated(true);


    }
    else{
        setContentPane(FullSettingsMenu);
        revalidate();
        setUndecorated(false);
    }
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Не работает почему-то. По нажатию,как ничего не происходило,так и не происходит. Вы пробовали запускать?

Comment: что ты ожидаешь получить от функции и что получаешь?

Comment: По выставлению флага,я хочу получить полноэкранный режим (`setUndecorated(true)`),а по снятию - оконный (`setUndecorated(false)`)

Comment: обновил ответ. все работает